# Show Hide Vuejs Element

Tags: vue.js, hide, element, show

**hello, I have a dilemma, trying to show and hide content from a list**

**I have an object in data**

```
{
     types : {
          key_1 : { code: 'code_1', text: 'hello 1', show: false },
          key_2 : { code: 'code_2', text: 'hello 2', show: false },
          key_3 : { code: 'code_3', text: 'hello 3', show: false },
          key_4 : { code: 'code_4', text: 'hello 4', show: false },
          key_5 : { code: 'code_5', text: 'hello 5', show: false },
    }
}
```

**and another in localStorage**

```
[
      { key_6 : { code: 'code_6', text: 'hello 6', show: false } },
      { key_7 : { code: 'code_7', text: 'hello 7', show: false } },
      { key_8 : { code: 'code_8', text: 'hello 8', show: false } },
      { key_9 : { code: 'code_9', text: 'hello 9', show: false } },
]
```

**in created**

```
created: function(){
    let datas = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('types'));
     datas.forEach( o => {
         this.types[o.code] = {
             text    : o.text,
             show : false,
         };
    });
},
```

**it works fine this.types, there are both lists**
**now there's an HTML**

```
<ul>
        <li v-for="(v,k) in types" :key="k">
              <a @click="opClo(k)">
                  <span>{{v.text}}</span>
              </a>
              <ol v-show="v.show">
                     <li>hello</li>
              </ol>
        </li>
</ul>
```

**in methods**

```
    opClo : function( key ){
        this.types[key].show = !this.types[key].show;
    },
```

> opClo would have to show or hide the `ol`, but it fails, it only opens the `data`, the challenge doesn't open them, how can this problem be solved?

Comment: The code in `created` and the example data from `localStorage` don't match up. `o` would be the wrapper object, with a single property called `key_6`, etc. `o.code` would be `undefined`.

Comment: in this case they are adding more items to the list `this.types`, at the end are, `key_1, key_2, ..., key_8, key_9` and is all the list from 1 to 9 that is painted and shows or hides its own `li`

Comment: That is not what the code you've posted does. Perhaps it's just a mistake in the example you've posted here but the code in `created` will not work with the example data you've posted for `localStorage`. Please check the code you've posted in the question, especially the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

for the record if someone else has the same problem,

the `datas.forEach` loop when assigning data directly to the `object`, it is to use `$set`

`this.$set(this.types, key, item)`

**This was the problem.**

> Anyway, I think the problem is that because you are adding the items from localStorage after the this.type property is created, the newly added items are not reactive.

see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats